# OpenRefine Troubleshooting

Tags: openrefine

I am trying to install the OpenRefine, but all I get is this message:

[image]

My JRE is up to date. I would appreciate your help, I am stuck. Thanks!
PS: win8.1 OS

Comment: There's a problem with Jython. What is your version of Open refine? For a technical issue, you will probably get better answers on the [Open Refine's Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/openrefine) or on its [Github page](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues).

Comment: It would also be useful to have the full error - some of the first lines seem to be missing here.

Comment: @10tons : Could you copy the entire stack trace from the Open Refine's console (CTRL+A, CTRL+C) and post it on [Github](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/1236#issuecomment-322687639) ?

Comment: Thanks, I reported a bug on OpenRefine github page. In case anyone's interested: https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/1236.